# How to append to a List of strings with values from another List?

Tags: c#

I have a basic List that looks something like this:

```
List<string> gameNames = new List<string>()
{
    "Zelda",
    "Mario",
    "Metroid",
    "Splatoon",
    "Xenoblade",
};
```

I have another List that looks something like this:

```
List<string> gameData = new List<string>()
{
    ", Nintendo, Nintendo, 2017",
    "Mario, Nintendo, Nintendo, 2017",
    ", Nintendo, Nintendo, 2017",
    ", Nintendo, Nintendo, 2017",
    "Xenoblade, Nintendo, Monolith, 2017",
};
```

I want to replace the first "," of the gameData List with the respective value in the same index of gameNames.

So, the first element should look like:

```
"Zelda, Nintendo, Nintendo, 2017"
```

Right now, I am using a Zip method that appends the data, but it doesn't check to see if the value is ',', it just appends no matter what.

Here is an example:

```
List<string> gameData= gameNames.Zip(gameData, (x, y) => x + "," + y).ToList();
```

Comment: how should the indexes [1] and [4] be treated, there the name of the game is already the first token of the gamedata - is that a copy/paste error or do you need deduplication of the first token as well?

Comment: If there is already data, like [1] and [4], I don't want it to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameData.Count(); i++)
{
   gameData[i] = gameNames[i] + gameData[i].Substring(gameData[i].IndexOf(","));
}
```

gameData[i].IndexOf(",") above will find the position of first "," and Substring will extract content after first ",". Then append contents from gameNames list.

Comment: `gameData` is a List already, meaning you can just call `.Count`.  If you use the Linq method `.Count()` it iterates the entire collection which is not efficient.  Also, how do you handle index out of range exceptions on `gameNames`?

Comment: actually `List<string>` is `ICollection` and `System.Linq.Enumerable.Count()` is [smart enough](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,1317) to simply return `ICollection.Count` in this case. At least in 4.7.2.

Comment: @dlatikay fair enough, still think using `.Count` would make more sense but at least there isnt a performance concern (assuming the right .NET version)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to add the leading comma logic to the lambda, and leave everything else intact:

```
var merged = gameNames.Zip(gameData, (x, y) => x + (y.StartsWith(", ") ? String.Empty : ", ") + y).ToList();
```

So it uses the leading comma where present, and inserts one where missing.

Second version after clarification in OP:

```
var merged = gameNames.Zip(gameData, (x, y) => (y.StartsWith(", ") ? x + y : y)).ToList();
```

This keeps the value of `gameNames` whenever it does not start with a comma+space, else concatenates.